# Creating new git repo by splitting existing repo using filter-repo

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

I need to take out few folders from existing big repo and create a new small repo. I then plan to use the small repo as a folder inside big repo using subtree. I think these two steps should work together. I am on Windows 10/ git 2.28.

For step 1 of splitting repo, I want to use git-filter-repo following @Ipearson answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

But all my folders are getting deleted after running following command:

```
git filter-repo --path dir1\dir2 --force
```

My directory structure is:
[image: directory structure]

I have to use force option otherwise it keeps saying that it is not a fresh clone. But I have cloned the repo in new directory!
[image: error if force is not used]

Here is the output for filter-repo command:

[image: filter-repo ran for 4 seconds]

I was expecting that dir2 inside dir1 will continue to exist.
I actually have to use multiple --path directories like following but that is also not working as expected.

```
git filter-repo --path dir0 --path dir1/dir2
```

So my questions are:

1. why do I need to use --force
2. why all the folders are removed after running filter-repo

Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between`filter-branch` and `filter-repo`.

Comment: @dan1st Yes, I read that filter-branch has known issues and I'm trying to avoid it.